# Getting NULL trying to return object from eqmcc() function in QCA package

Tags: r, null

I keep getting a NULL returned when running the exact same script provided in the QCA package documentation:

```
data(d.represent)
Krook<-d.represent
KrookTT <- truthTable(Krook, outcome = "WNP")
KrookSI <- eqmcc(KrookTT, include = "?", direxp = c(1,1,1,1,1), details =TRUE)
KrookSI$PIchart$i.sol$C1P1
```

That returns a NULL as does the following:

```
KrookSI$pims$i.sol$C1P1
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: library(QCA); data(d.represent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all I needed to was the following:

```
   KrookSP$pims
   KrookSP$PIchart
```